# Полукошеная трава (или же два "н"?)

Tags: орфография

В справочнике Л-на написано, что в сложных словах мы сохраняем столько же *н* в причастии, сколько оно само по себе-с имеет-таки. (В 99-м параграфе: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52.) Однако я не могу понять, является ли прич. сложным, если я к нему *полу-* прибавляю. Я боюсь, что *полу-* в данном случае - это просто-напросто приставка, из-за чего кол-во *н* должно равняться двум всё равно.

Как правильно писать *полукошеная трава*, совы?

Comment: Полукошеная... да щё и трава. Это о травке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Есть причастие ***скошенный*** ([kartaslov.ru](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)), и есть прилагательное ***кошеный*** ([kartaslov.ru](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)), например: *кошеный луг, скошенное сено*.

Слова "полукошеный" и "полускошенный" в речи практически не используются, но их **смысл понятен**. Так говорится о результатах незаконченной работы.

2. **Формант ПОЛУ-** называют префиксом/приставкой, корнем, но лучше других название «префиксоид».  ПОЛУ-   входит в состав сложных слов в качестве корневой основы,  но самостоятельным корнем быть не может и практически используется **на правах приставки.**

В частности формант ПОЛУ- по значению близок **к приставке НЕДО**-, и они оба определяют **количественную** оценку признака:  полузабытый, недоразвитый.

3. **Теоретически** мы могли бы иметь следующие **варианты:** *кошеная трава, некошеная трава* (прилагательные) , но *недокошенная трава, полукошенная трава* (причастия).

Приставка  ПОЛУ- определяет **переход прилагательного в причастие** по обычным правилам  (это уже признак действия, а не качественный признак).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Итак, в словаре, а также в литературных текстах нет прилагательного ***полукошеный*** и причастия ***полукошенный***, но можно представить ситуации, где они могли бы использоваться.

(1) *Так и остался луг **полускошеным**, с неровными рядами* (прилагательное, качественный признак).

(2) *Луг **полускошенный**, когда ты наконец закончишь работу* (причастие, признак по действию).

Comment: А не являются ли слова, имеющие *полу-*, сложными словами, а не словами с префиксом?  Если так, то нам надо же ону *н* писать. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80. По этой ссылке можно в 151-м параграфе увидеть, что написано там "сложные слова", и там 1-е слово - это слово, имеющие *полу-*, поэтому я и-с боюсь, сэр.

Comment: Мнение Грамоты.ру. ПОЛУ – это префиксоид. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=префиксоид   По определению, префиксоид – это корневая морфема, выступающая в функции приставки (префикса) . С этой точки зрения  рассматривают все вопросы, связанные с ПОЛУ. В словарях  же сказано, что это первая часть сложных слов,

Comment: И как писать тогда?

Comment: Пишите: полукошенный.  По образцу: кошеный  – полукошенный, недокошенный, скошенный. Орфографический редактор подчеркивает слова, которых нет в словаре. Полукошеный? Тоже подчеркивает.